# Why Doctrine Dbal package driver not found when i have installed via composer?

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I am working on a project where i have to use PostgreSQL and laravel. For PostgreSQL setup i have un commented required extension.
But when i need to change the data type of certain column and try to migrate it then it gives me error.
***Class 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOPgSql\Driver' not found
at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/PostgresConnection.php:91***
.
I have removed and reinstalled Doctrine package but still gives me same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

If this not works, check What is your doctrine/dbal version. If the version is `3 or more`. There is an issue with that. Please update your compoer.json file with `lower version of dctrine/dbal (2.12)`. And Run

```
composer update.
```

Comment: package installs successfully but the problem is when i try to migrate it says driver not found

Comment: What is your doctrine/dbal version. If the version is 3 or more. There is issue with that. Please update your compoer.json file with lower version of dctrine/dbal (2.12). And Run composer update.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you may need to upgrade composet itself via:

```
composer selfupdate --2
```

or

```
composer selfupdate -2
```

then run the following command:

```
composer update -W -o
```

Comment: Successfully updated composer but the error is same

Comment: Yes but the package is installed successfully. Maybe it is because i switched mysql to pgsql

Comment: yeah maybe is the reason you get the error

Comment: sorry that i couldn't help you